# Where can I find a calender plugin for Classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, calendar

Hi I'm looking for a jQuery, JS, or PHP code that will allow me to display a calender with predetermined classes available for booking, i.e. a calender that displays the time of classes available at the local gym for each day and allows for possible bookings, even just allows an external link to another booking page would be ok. I've been looking for this for a few days now and have had no luck. My apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology and this has been covered many times before.

Regards,

Chris

Comment: You can try http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

Where I live a lot of gyms use https://www.mindbodyonline.com for class timetables and booking.

Example: http://www.thefitnessplayground.com.au/timetable